# Dynamic Swagger generation

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-2.0

We want to dynamically generate swagger documentation for our CRUD restful API. We have an API which allows consumers to create an entity e.g. User. Now we want to generate REST API definition for the created entity dynamically as the entity created can be any object e.g User, Organization, Institution. We have functionality in place to generate meta data for the given entity which will basically describe the entity created (properties, their validations etc.) .

Is there an API by which we can write the swagger definition by using the meta data as an input? It will allow us to have Swagger definition for each of the entity we create dynamically. We are using Spring Framework.

Comment: This is exactly that I need too.